# Процесс завершается сам по себе

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Я запускаю MTA (Multi Theft Auto) процесс сервера в фоновом режиме.
Проходит какое то время - он сам по себе тухнет, никаких предпосылок, ни переполнение памяти, никаких внешних вмешательств не было.
Может быть такое, что в linux имеется максимальное время действия процесса?

Comment: может ООМ киллер прибежал, а может просто код бажный

Comment: что такое ООМ кликер?)

Comment: это такая подсистема в ядре, которая прибивает приложение, когда системе не хватает памяти. К примеру, запустили скрипт, которому нужно очень-очень-очень много памяти - другие приложения могут пострадать.

Comment: @KoVadim я много раз слышал об этом чуде, но каждый раз когда моей системе начинает не хватать памяти, курсор просто перестаёт двигаться и ничего кроме перезагрузки не помогает. Я пользуюсь линуксом уже около 15 лет и ни на одном дистрибутве не видел ООМ-киллера в действии, а так хотелось бы!

Comment: возможно, Вы просто настраивали немного своп и окресности